# Is it possible to use Fuerte on 14.04?

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

currently I am using Fuerte on 12.04. I think about upgrading to 14.04 but I am not sure if Fuerte will work then!?
Someone tried it?

Regards Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201364/is-it-possible-to-use-fuerte-on-14.04?/) by [maxlein](https://answers.ros.org/users/21426/maxlein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's [REP0003 - Target Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for answering such questions. As you can see, there is no official support for ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 14.04. This does not mean that it is completely impossible to run a Fuerte setup on 14.04, but that you'd have to try this yourself (building from source) and likely end up in a world of hurt due to various build issues as libraries changed etc.

In short, I'd strongly recommend to port your code to ROS Indigo if at all possible as opposed to trying to make Fuerte run on 14.04.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2015-01-20**:
I agree. Running Fuerte on 14.04 will very likely be painful. In almost all cases it will be easier to port your code to Indigo.